# How do I keep the text in middle, without affecting the images? CSS. (Wordpress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Here is [my site](http://defensionem.com/2015/09/14/us-military-demo-3/) It is on wordpress, and I want to keep the text(article) in the center so as it is easier for people to read.

I used padding, to push the text in the center.

```
.article-body-wrap {
padding-left:275px;
}

div[itemprop="articleBody"] p {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}
```

These two did the job, but then I am unable to have wider images due to padding.

I tried using this,

```
.attachment_12210{
padding-left: 10px !important;
}
```

But it did not help. How do I keep the text in the middle but make sure the images are wide and large enough? Something like [Medium.com](https://medium.com/bright/for-silicon-valley-hopefuls-is-college-irrelevant-89ffb15dbe82)

Comment: Adding padding to center the text is not a good practice. Did you notice the example website is not using a widget (Right hand side bar). But on your site some part of the page width is taken by the widget. Best solution will be remove the widget and make your article use full-width. Doing this you can define width for text part and images will be full width. If you don't want to remove the widget you can move it down in footer or any place other than inline with article.

Comment: Alright, I understand, removing the sidebar is easy. But then, I want the text to be in the center rather than full width. How do I only keep the text in the middle but images are larger on the other hand? Thanks for the help Akash. :)

Comment: Set a `max-width: ??%; display: block; margin: 0 auto;` for text container only. It'll work

Comment: Akash I tried and I put a margin as around 300px. Sadly, it also affected the images inside the article box.

Comment: don't put a margin. Use this css `.article-body-wrap p { max-width: 60%; display: block; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; }`
Let me know if it doesn't work.
OR if you can put the text in another container add this css to that container. That'll be better.

Comment: It did not work. It did nothing infact.

Comment: I checked the page. you added ??% and gave 300px margin. Sorry for that but for ?? you had to use a value and keep margin as same as I provided. I've tested it and its working

Comment: Use the complete CSS I gave in second comment and remove the one you added earlier.

Comment: Nope, I added it latter. The thing is I want the text to be around 300px away, near the middle of the screen. (I could easily achieve that by margin or padding.) But then it also affects my images. I want my images however to remain large. I have put your code and it is same as default theme layout. (I wanted something like medium.com)

Comment: I've checked my code and it worked. I'd suggest you an easy way to do this. You don't have to dive into code. I've noticed that your site is using bootstrap. You can use a plugin `https://wordpress.org/plugins/bootstrap-shortcodes/` it'll help you. Let me know if I can help you any other way.

Comment: Something must be overriding the custom CSS?

Comment: I tested the code. Nothing was overriding. You didn't put the right css. 
`.article-body-wrap p { max-width: 60%; display: block; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; } ` this is what you had to add. Don't change any other attribute other than percentage on max-width.
And while adding content on backend, make sure you don't wrap the images in `<p>...</p>` tag. You can check that using 'TEXT VIEW' from top right of content editor.

Answer (score 1):

there are many variations of solving your problem.

I would probably create a div around the text, define the div's position and give the text the property **text-align:center;** and then define the width of the div to always keep it centered.

read more at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align

/S

Comment: Thanks, albeit I would want the text to be in the centre and a little bit more inside. I edited and used text-align:center.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have

```
<section class="article-body-wrap"></section>
```

Your CSS is applied to the entire section. So any padding you apply to that section will affect any images within the section tag.

```
<section class="article-body-wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imgDiv">
       <img src="">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
       <p>...</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Have a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x50bykk8/

article-body-wrap aligns your text to be centered.

.container applies the padding to the text.

your image is outside of the container element, and so does not have to be the same width as your text element.

Comment: It also affects the images inside the article body though. Something like only text in the middle and a bit large images, like the one on medium.com?

Comment: So, what do I exactly add to the Custom CSS in Wordpress?

Comment: If this is how you want all your pages to appear, then you would want to edit  your default template file. wp-content/themes/theme_name/library/index.php 

Adding your html to the section wherever your content is posted

if it's just one page you wish to appear like this, then you would make another page template.

Then apply the css to your stylesheet.

if it's your first time editting your default template file, i suggest making a backup